# How recommended is using custom double underscore variables in Python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I was wondering, is it recommended/Pythonic to define and use custom double underscore variables/functions in a Python script? For example, `__tablename__` as used in SQLAlchemy or `__validateitem__()` (a custom function that validates an item before applying `__setitem__()` to it).

If it does define that something magic happens, or that that specific variable/function is used indeed in a special way (like the two above examples), I feel it is a good idea using them.

I am interested in arguments on both best coding practices and potential risks in using this kind of naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From PEP8:

> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

So, the advice is not to use the double underscore syntax for your own variables.

Comment: Is it because it can mislead users to think it is a standard defined name? Or is it because it's meant to be future-proof, as anytime a variable with that name can be implemented in the standard library? There are cases when _exactly_ this is intended and emphasized with these names, that something "magic" occurs.

Comment: User defined __ are a private marker. Since python is interpreted, there is not realy private var/method. Use only one underscore to mark your vars as "be careful".The acces of __vars is slower than usual, so you have no reason to use this.

Comment: What backs the interpretation that a programmer should not invent such a name? My problem is, programmers are writing apis for programmers here. Which one is the "your own" programmer?

Comment: taken the question to be at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965088/never-invent-such-names-only-use-them-as-documented-who