# "Never invent such names; only use them as documented." Who?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, terminology, pep8

I read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for to know whether (an imaginary) me creating an object with a name such as `__foo__` is a good idea or not. PEP 8 says this about `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`:

> Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

My question is: who?

I am a programmer. I write an API for other programmers. Python was implemented by programmers. The language reference for the implementation was written by programmers or at least ex-programmers, and the programmers using my API will write something that may or may not be used by further programmers.

Now this unfolded, which programmer is PEP 8 speaking of when they say, "Never invent such names"?

*Someone* is obviously encouraged to invent such names, since they exist, while others are uninvited to do so.

***Which group of programmers should "Never invent such names" ?***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are discouraged from using such names in your APIs, yes, because if and when the *Python core developers* pick the same name for Python itself, you'll lose out, your API can break.

So, if you are not a Python core developer or writing a PEP that may be one day become part of the Python standard library or core language definition, try to stay away from using dunder names in your API.